# Is it a good practice to put functions in is javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, performance, object

I made a constructor, and am planning to make a large number of objects.

```
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;

    this.meow = function () {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Say, function meow() is a very lengthy. Will it become a memory problem if I create many cats or does javascript take care of it? Is it better to create a static function, rather then a function within an object in such case?

Comment: Usually you put functions in the prototype, rather than in each instance.

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding [modern JS's dedicated support for classes via the `class` keyword](https://javascript.info/class)? Using them would remove the concern; the JS interpreter should be using whatever solution works best automatically, without worrying about whether you're accidentally creating a closure per-instance (as it happens, it's basically creating a prototype with a single copy of each method for you).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the `meow` function is lengthy or not. It creates a new function object for every instance, which becomes a problem if you have zillions of instances. The code size of the body doesn't affect the memory used for one of these function objects.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No sure what you mean by "*it's basically creating a prototype with a single copy of each method*"?

Comment: @Bergi: The solution given in the other answers, to manually attach a function to `Cat.prototype`, a la `Cat.prototype.meow = function() {};` is what modern `class` syntax does automatically behind the scenes. The function is created once and the single copy is bound to the prototype. Every instance of `Cat` finds that single copy when you try to look up `instance.meow`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ah, I though that part was referring to "*creating a closure per instance*", where it didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use a prototype for this.

```
function Cat(name) {}
Cat.prototype.meow = function(){};
```

Most modern engines (including chrome's V8) will optimize the object creation into a reusable path, whereas if this.meow is used then a custom hidden path is defined at each instantiation.

Does better turn into a micro optimization though? That really depends on your implementation and environment.

For a more thorough explanation of the way that the prototype enhances performance, see this medium explanation from V8 developer Toon Verwaest, [*Setting up prototypes in V8*](https://medium.com/@tverwaes/setting-up-prototypes-in-v8-ec9c9491dfe2).

Comment: "*if this.meow is used then a custom hidden path is defined at each instantiation*" - that doesn't sound right. Am I misunderstanding what you are referring to?

Comment: @Bergi - I am not sure? Let me expand and you can tell me. Using `this.meow` to attach the function will be part of the transitioning object, which uses hidden classes to create an entire hidden path, this path is discovered and creating when using `new Cat()`. Using a prototype will create a specific hidden class for that prototype object which gets reused and does not need to be created each time when using `new Cat()`.

Comment: The transitioning path and the hidden class is the same for all `Cat` objects, it does not need to be created each time the constructor is called, that's the whole point of the system.

Comment: @Bergi - I do not believe that it is the same for all implementations of the Cat class. The transitioning path will be the same as the previous call to the constructor, however, it will not be the same as the modified version with the properties attached using `this.`. I believe those are required to be discovered each time as they are not added using the constructor itself, but rather in the function executing once the object is created. This is the core difference between using a prototype (which initializes with a custom tailored path versus not which requires modification each time).

Comment: Are we talking about the same code here? There is only one implementation of the `Cat` class. All instantiations will follow the same hidden class transition path (that was created on the first call) while the constructor initialises the properties - and it absolutely doesn't matter whether the property value is a function or something else. Not sure what you mean by "*not in the constructor itself, but rather in the function executing once the object is created*". The methods don't create new properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can add function to Cat's prototype. This way, any call to meow will reference the same function.

```
Cat.prototype.meow = function() {};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: It's not expensive. **Long answer**: Look into Functional programming vs Object Oriented Programming. With JavaScript functional programming will allow you to do all sorts of neat things like for example:

```
function add(a, b)
{
   return a + b;
}

function subtract5(a)
{
   return a - 5; 
}

//You can pass functions into functions like:  subtract5(add(3, 3)) = 1;
```

Then you can also use functional programming languages to make your life easier with functions like find, forEach, map, reduce it takes in a conditional function to apply it to the array you are working with...for example:

```
 function condition(x)
 {
  return x.id == 2;
 }
 var users = []
 users.push({ 
  id:1,
  name:"Bob"
 });
 users.push({ 
  id:2,
   name:"Dan"
 })
// users.find(condition).name is equal to Dan
//The condition function can be a lot of things which is why it's so powerful
```

Another great example (I used this format in a javascript game with a lot of inside functions and it showed no negative 
performance )

```
  var Cat = function(param)
 {
    var self = {}; 
    self.name = param.name;
    self.age = param.age;
    self.birthday = function()
    {
      self.age++;
    }
    return self;
 } 
  var youngCat = new Cat({name: "Ginger", age: 2});
  youngCat.birthday();
```

Comment: `forEach` is not functional programming. And really I don't see how this answers the question, your `Cat` constructor still has the same problem as the code of the OP.

Comment: I had no problems with my "cat" example. As stated above I made a pretty hefty javascript game in Node.Js and every element (players, items, etc) all used thats system. It was a MOBA so there were a lot of players on the same field and I saw no performance issues. Also, I'm talking about array.forEach NOT foreach(...). Here is an article that explains it well: https://medium.com/@eliaai/javascript-functional-programming-foreach-map-filter-reduce-f710abb69753

Comment: "a lot of players" means what, a few hundreds? And yes, I'm talking about the array method. Just taking a callback function doesn't make something functional.

Comment: Maybe I worded it wrong. I mean obviously there is a cost I'm just saying it's very small and not noticeable and won't cause the OP's computer to crash because he as 10000 cats created. To answer your question there are were 10 players at once (MOBA like league of legends it's 5v5)